# Bokeh: Locate a widget in a picture

Tags: bokeh

In the picture, my current website is shown. At the top, there is a graph generated with bokeh. Below that is a slider. In the diagram this is the red line, which is a bokeh span. With said slider, I can move the span in the diagram. Below the slider is a picture on the left and an entry field on the right they are implemented with the following code:

```py
#Generates a widget that holds the picture of the mill
mill_image = Div(   text="""
                         <img src="/static/images/milling_plant.png" 
                          alt="div_image" 
                          width="700">""", 
                          width=700, 
                          height=150)

#Generates a widget that holds the entry field
text_clas_speed = TextInput(value="0", 
                           title=_("classifier speed"),
                           width=100)
```

The input field is kind of abused, as it will not get an input, but display a value. The displayed value is the value highlighted with the red span in the diagram. It dynamically changes when the slider is moved. 
All this works fine.

[image: my current website]

Now to my question: What I want to do is to place the input field somewhere in the picture. I'm thinking of setting its position with coordinates. Currently, I'm giving the position with the following code.

```py
output = column(
           p, #Graph
           time_slider, #Slider
           row(
             mill_image, #Picture
             text_clas_speed, #Input field that displays the value
             widgetbox(checkbox_group), #Some checkboxes not visable in the screenshot
           ) 
         )
```

In the result, there is probably not the text_clas_speed in this structure and it comes with the mill_image. At the moment, I have no idea how I could get this done. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh's built-in layout system does not have any notion of or capability for overlapping elements, so it is not possible to overlap the control over the image with pure Bokeh. You would need to create an Jinja HTML template that somehow positions divs in an overlapping fashion, then use Bokeh's embed APIs to place individual components in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think for the first I will just arrange the input fields around the image.